# Should it be "clothes" or "clothing" in the following list?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

> She never lacked food, **clothing**, or a bed.
>
> She never lacked food, **clothes**, or a bed.

Should it be clothes or clothing? And why? (Maybe both are okay?)

Comment: Both are OK. _Clothes_ can refer to a particular set of garments or, as here, to clothing in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either 'clothes' or 'clothing' would work in your examples. The difference between them are that if you use the word clothes you are referring to a large but finite amount (of clothing), while using the word 'clothing' potentially means she has an infinite source of clothes.

Comment: Surely **the difference between them IS...**  And **an infinite source** of clothing is not the same as **unlimited** , not even for the Kardashians.

Comment: "Clothes" does not refer to any particular amount. "Clothing" refers to the concept of clothes in general, not an infinite supply